# What is the recommended way to escape HTML symbols in plain Java?

Tags: java, html, escaping

Is there a recommended way to escape `<`, `>`, `"` and `&` characters when outputting HTML in plain Java code?  (Other than manually doing the following, that is).

```
String source = "The less than sign (<) and ampersand (&) must be escaped before using them in HTML";
String escaped = source.replace("<", "&lt;").replace("&", "&amp;"); // ...
```

Comment: Be aware that if you are outputting into an unquoted HTML attribute, that other characters such as space, tab, backspace, etc... can allow attackers to introduce javascript attributes without any of the characters listed. See the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet for more.

Comment: BTW, in this code, you should escape "&" before "<" for this to work properly ("&lt;" get replaced with "&amp;lt;" otherwise, which is rendered as "&lt;" then, not "<"): `source.replace("&", "&amp;").replace("<", "&lt;");`

Answer (score 289):

[StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml;
// ...
String source = "The less than sign (<) and ampersand (&) must be escaped before using them in HTML";
String escaped = escapeHtml(source);
```

For [version 3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String)):

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4;
// ...
String escaped = escapeHtml4(source);
```

Comment: While `StringEscapeUtils` is nice it will not escape whitespace properly for attributes if you wish to avoid HTML/XML whitespace normalization. See my answer for greater detail.

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml() only accepts String as input, which seems unnecessarily rigid. In this modern world of JSON, some things output to the page will be numbers, for example, in which case this method breaks.

Comment: The above example is broken. Use escapeHtml4() method now.

Comment: For Guava fans see [okranz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26572556/245602) below.

Comment: If webpage has UTF-8 encoding then all we need is Guava's htmlEscaper that escapes only the following five ASCII characters: '"&<>.

The Apache's escapeHtml() also replaces non-ASCII characters including  accents which seems unnecessary with UTF-8 web pages ?

Comment: @greim - When might numbers contain content that needs to be escaped?

Comment: @dfa- When I use escapeHtml(input), the double quot (") in my HTML string  gets converted to &quot; which I don't want. Is there any way to customize that?

Comment: It is now deprecated in commons-lang3. It was moved to  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/597419/danny - that link does not mention escaping HTML. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Here is a direct link to the latest namespace at [org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4-java.lang.String-) as @Danny mentioned

Comment: NOTE:  StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml dos not escape the apostrophe character, leaving you with a big bug or even security vulnerability. Use other working tools, like Spring HtmUtils or others mentioned.

Comment: Use `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils` for `apache.commons.text`

Answer (score 167):

An alternative to Apache Commons: Use [Spring](http://www.springframework.org)'s `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(String input)` method.

Comment: Thanks. I've used it (instead of `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` from `apache-commons` 2.6) because it leaves Russian characters as is.

Comment: That's good to know.  TBH I give Apache stuff a wide berth these days.

Comment: I've used it, too,  it leaves Chinese characters as is, too.

Comment: And it also encodes the apostrophe, so it is actually useful, unlike apache StringEscapeUtils

Answer (score 66):

Nice short method:

```
public static String escapeHTML(String s) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(Math.max(16, s.length()));
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c > 127 || c == '"' || c == '\'' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '&') {
            out.append("&#");
            out.append((int) c);
            out.append(';');
        } else {
            out.append(c);
        }
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838023/1199155 (the amp is missing there). The four characters checked in the if clause are the only ones below 128, according to http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

Comment: Nice. It doesn't use the "html versions" of the encodings (example: "á" would be "&aacute;" instead of "&#225;"), but since the numeric ones work even in IE7 I guess I don't have to worry. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you encode all that characters when the OP asked to escape the 4 relevant characters? You are wasting CPU and memory.

Comment: You forgot the apostrophe. So people can inject unquoted attributes everywhere where this code is used to escape attribute values.

Comment: this does not work when the string contains surrogate pairs, e.g. emojis.

Answer (score 47):

There is a newer version of the [Apache Commons Lang library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.0/index.html) and it uses a different package name (org.apache.commons.lang3). The `StringEscapeUtils` now has different static methods for escaping different types of documents (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.0/index.html). So to escape HTML version 4.0 string:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4;

String output = escapeHtml4("The less than sign (<) and ampersand (&) must be escaped before using them in HTML");
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing exists for HTML 5, nor do the Apache documents specify if it is proper to use escapeHtml4 for HTML 5.

Comment: `escapeHtml4` has been moved to org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.

Answer (score 46):

For those who use Google Guava:

```
import com.google.common.html.HtmlEscapers;
[...]
String source = "The less than sign (<) and ampersand (&) must be escaped before using them in HTML";
String escaped = HtmlEscapers.htmlEscaper().escape(source);
```

Comment: Where can I use the same, but for unescape?

Answer (score 43):

Be careful with this.  There are a number of different 'contexts' within an HTML document: Inside an element, quoted attribute value, unquoted attribute value, URL attribute, javascript, CSS, etc...  You'll need to use a different encoding method for each of these to prevent Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).  Check [the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) for details on each of these contexts. You can find escaping methods for each of these contexts in the OWASP ESAPI library -- https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy.

Comment: THANK YOU for pointing out that the *context* in which you wish to encode the output very much matters.  The term "encode" is also a much more appropriate verb than "escape", as well.  Escape implies some kind of special hack, as opposed to "how do I *encode* this string for: an XHTML attribute / SQL query parameter / PostScript print string / CSV output field?

Comment: 'Encode' and 'escape' are both widely used to describe this. The term "escape" is generally used when the process is to add an "escape character" before a syntactically-relevant character, such as escaping a quote character with a backslash \"   The term "encode" is more typically used when you translate a character into a different form, such as URL encoding the quote character %22 or HTML entity encoding as &#x22 or @quot.

Comment: http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/index.html. link now broke

Comment: To save you some googling, look for the Encoder class https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#encodeForHTMLAttribute(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 40):

On android (API 16 or greater) you can:

```
Html.escapeHtml(textToScape);
```

or for lower API:

```
TextUtils.htmlEncode(textToScape);
```

Comment: See also my [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104032/whats-the-difference-between-androids-html-escapehtml-and-textutils-htmlencode) about the difference between these two. (@Muz )

Comment: What about unescape?

Answer (score 20):

For some purposes, [HtmlUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html):

```
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils;
[...]
HtmlUtils.htmlEscapeDecimal("&"); //gives &#38;
HtmlUtils.htmlEscape("&"); //gives &amp;
```

Comment: From the spring HtmlUtils comments:
 * <p>For a comprehensive set of String escaping utilities,
 * consider Apache Commons Lang and its StringEscapeUtils class.
 * We are not using that class here to avoid a runtime dependency
 * on Commons Lang just for HTML escaping. Furthermore, Spring's
 * HTML escaping is more flexible and 100% HTML 4.0 compliant.

If you are already using Apache commons in your project probably you should use the StringEscapeUtils from apache

Answer (score 16):

org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils is now deprecated. You must now use org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils by

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.text.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 14):

While @dfa answer of `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` is nice and I have used it in the past it should not be used for escaping HTML (or XML) **attributes** otherwise the whitespace will be normalized (meaning all adjacent whitespace characters become a single space).

I know this because I have had bugs filed against my library (JATL) for attributes where whitespace was not preserved. Thus I have a drop in (copy n' paste) [class (of which I stole some from JDOM) that differentiates the escaping of attributes and element content](https://code.google.com/p/jatl/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jatl/MarkupUtils.java).

While this may not have mattered as much in the past (proper attribute escaping) it is increasingly become of greater interest given the use use of HTML5's `data-` attribute usage.

Answer (score 1):

The most of libraries offer escaping everything they can including hundreds of symbols and thousands of non-ASCII characters which is not what you want in UTF-8 world.

Also, as Jeff Williams noted, there's no single “escape HTML” option, there are several contexts.

Assuming you never use unquoted attributes, and keeping in mind that different contexts exist, it've written my own version:

```java
private static final long TEXT_ESCAPE =
        1L << '&' | 1L << '<';
private static final long DOUBLE_QUOTED_ATTR_ESCAPE =
        TEXT_ESCAPE | 1L << '"';
private static final long SINGLE_QUOTED_ATTR_ESCAPE =
        TEXT_ESCAPE | 1L << '\'';
private static final long ESCAPES =
        DOUBLE_QUOTED_ATTR_ESCAPE | SINGLE_QUOTED_ATTR_ESCAPE;

// 'quot' and 'apos' are 1 char longer than '#34' and '#39'
// which I've decided to use
private static final String REPLACEMENTS = "&#34;&amp;&#39;&lt;";
private static final int REPL_SLICES = /*  [0,   5,   10,  15, 19) */
        5<<5 | 10<<10 | 15<<15 | 19<<20;
// These 5-bit numbers packed into a single int
// are indices within REPLACEMENTS which is a 'flat' String[]

private static void appendEscaped(
        Appendable builder, CharSequence content, long escapes) {
    try {
        int startIdx = 0, len = content.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = content.charAt(i);
            long one;
            if (((c & 63) == c) && ((one = 1L << c) & escapes) != 0) {
            // -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            // |                  | take only dangerous characters
            // | java shifts longs by 6 least significant bits,
            // | e. g. << 0b110111111 is same as >> 0b111111.
            // | Filter out bigger characters

                int index = Long.bitCount(ESCAPES & (one - 1));
                builder.append(content, startIdx, i /* exclusive */).append(
                        REPLACEMENTS,
                        REPL_SLICES >>> (5 * index) & 31,
                        REPL_SLICES >>> (5 * (index + 1)) & 31
                );
                startIdx = i + 1;
            }
        }
        builder.append(content, startIdx, len);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // typically, our Appendable is StringBuilder which does not throw;
        // also, there's no way to declare 'if A#append() throws E,
        // then appendEscaped() throws E, too'
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

Consider copy-pasting from [Gist without line length limit](https://gist.github.com/Miha-x64/4ed50f1d5593e45a452efbf456aa1db4).

**UPD**: As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/3050249) suggests, `>` escaping is not necessary; also, `"` within `attr='…'` is allowed, too. I've updated the code accordingly.

You may [check it out](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) yourself:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>

<p title="&lt;&#34;I'm double-quoted!&#34;>">&lt;"Hello!"></p>
<p title='&lt;"I&#39;m single-quoted!">'>&lt;"Goodbye!"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8+ Solution:

```java
public static String escapeHTML(String str) {
    return str.chars().mapToObj(c -> c > 127 || "\"'<>&".indexOf(c) != -1 ?
       "&#" + c + ";" : String.valueOf((char) c)).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

[`String#chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) returns an `IntStream` of the char values from the String. We can then use `mapToObj` to escape the characters with a character code greater than 127 (non-ASCII characters) as well as the double quote (`"`), single quote (`'`), left angle bracket (`<`), right angle bracket (`>`), and ampersand (`&`). `Collectors.joining` concatenates the `String`s back together.

To better handle Unicode characters, `String#codePoints` can be used instead.

```
public static String escapeHTML(String str) {
    return str.codePoints().mapToObj(c -> c > 127 || "\"'<>&".indexOf(c) != -1 ?
            "&#" + c + ";" : new String(Character.toChars(c)))
       .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```