# Xml output on HTML

Tags: java, html, xml

My xml data =
`&lt;Item "/api/items/4000000002011"&gt;&lt;ItemID&gt;4000000002011&lt;/ItemID&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Sample Item1&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Description&gt;Sample Description&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;Rate&gt;34.00&lt;/Rate&gt;&lt;Tax1Name&gt;PST&lt;/Tax1Name&gt;&lt;Tax1Percentage&gt;8&lt;/Tax1Percentage&gt;&lt;Tax2Name/&gt;&lt;Tax2Percentage/&gt;&lt;/Item&gt;`

Html output=`<Item uri="/api/items/4000000002011"> <ItemID>4000000002011</ItemID><Name>Sample Item1</Name><Description>Sample Description</Description><Rate>34.00</Rate><Tax1Name>PST</Tax1Name><Tax1Percentage>8</Tax1Percentage><Tax2Name/><Tax2Percentage/></Item>`

I want to html output.How do I?

```
<Item "/api/items/4000000002011">
 <ItemID>4000000002011</ItemID>
 <Name>Sample Item1</Name>
 <Description>Sample Description</Description>
 <Rate>34.00</Rate>
 <Tax1Name>PST</Tax1Name>
 <Tax1Percentage>8</Tax1Percentage>
 <Tax2Name/>
 <Tax2Percentage/>
</Item>
```

Comment: Using what platform / language?

Comment: Xml data using mysql.Language java.

Comment: `<Item "/api/items/4000000002011">` - Since when was that valid XML?

Answer (score 1):

Just output the raw data as is, with &lt; and &gt;. Don't unescape before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

[Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

Are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use the [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) method in the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) API.

Alternatively, simply escape the XML entities - i.e. replace

```
>     <     "     &     '
```

with

```
&gt; &lt; &quot; &amp; &apos;
```