# how to store querystring value in variable

Tags: jquery, jsp, query-string

I am getting the value from error.jsp to staff.jsp page.

```
Welcome to <%= (String)request.getParameter("facilityname")%>
```

I have a form in staff.jsp page. When the user enter invalid username or password staff.jsp page refreshes and shows error, now at the top of page where I am getting the clinic name getting

null value and my page becomes like

```
Welcome to null.
```

How can i solve this please?

Comment: Can you show the form's markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more of the code (markup for the form, for instance), it's hard to say, but:

If "facilityname" really is the `name` of a field in the form being submitted, then you should be getting that field's value from `getParameter` and so that code should work (although it will fail if the page is refreshed without a form being submitted). Did you use an `id` rather than a name on the field? Is the capitalization correct?

If you want the page to work properly regardless of whether the form was submitted:

```
<%
String facilityname;

facilityname = (String)request.getParameter("facilityname");
if (facilityname != null && facilityname.length > 0) {
    out.print("Welcome to " + facilityname + ".");
}
%>
```

Of course, that (like your original) is inviting someone to inject HTML markup on up your page, since it doesn't escape any HTML characters in the input. You *definitely* need to do that with one of the several utility classes available (various ways recommended in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java) on SO).

Comment: Welcome to <%= (String)request.getParameter("facilityname")%>
I am getting parameter outside the form. This parameter only shows clinic name. This parameter have nothing to do with form. Problem is when staff.jsp refreshes i get the null value in facility name.

Comment: @Bilal: You'll have to explain more thoroughly what you're doing and where control is getting passed from page to page. *In general*, since a query string parameter is specific to a request (it's part of the `GET`), it won't get magically preserved moving from page to page, you have to ensure that it's in the page's URL (on the `form` `action`, for instance).

Comment: @Bilal: Good deal, glad that was of some help!