# how to insert %20 in place of space in android

Tags: java, android, urlencode

I have a xml URL file in which there are white spaces i want to replace white spaces with %20.. how to do this????

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

/** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                "http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?gallery=MALBA%20-%20MUSEO%20DE%20ARTE%20LATINOAMERICANO%20DE%20BUENOS%20AIRES");

XMLHandlerartistspace myXMLHandler = new XMLHandlerartistspace();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")` is the solution.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```
String temp = http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?gallery=MALBA%20-%20MUSEO%20DE%20ARTE%20LATINOAMERICANO%20DE%20BUENOS%20AIRES

temp = temp.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
URL sourceUrl = new URL(temp);
```

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach. The URL (excluding the host part) should be URL-encoded (using `URLEncoder.encode`). After doing that, you can replace the `+` characters with `%20`. If you don't use `URLEncoder.encode`, then there's the risk that other special characters in the URL might cause problems. (Note that `+` to represent a space character is perfectly valid in a URL; you might not even need `%20`.)

Comment: Do note that URI.Builder solution below is correct. This gets the job done.. but in a professional setting you want the solution from SudoCode

Answer (score 35):

When you build your URL you should use [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode the parameters.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("gallery=");
query.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
```

If you already have the whole URL in a String or a java.net.URL, you could grab the query part and rebuild while URLEncoding each parameter value.

Comment: This is the right way. If you are using a regex yourself or replaceAll then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: But be sure that you dont URL encode the host part of the url and the '/' characters inside the url. try a substring of the complete url or do it in the build process as sudocode suggested with a string builder.

Comment: If for some reason OP can't live with `+` representing spaces and really needs `%20`, it's easy enough to call `replace("+", "%20")` after calling `URLEncoder.encode`.

Comment: why `query.append("gallery=");` ?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat the parameter name and equals sign do not need to be URL encoded. The parameter value should be.

Answer (score 23):

Just one addition to sudocode's response:

Use `android.net.Uri.encode` instead of `URLEncoder.encode` to avoid the "spaces getting converted into +" problem. Then you get rid of the `String.replaceAll()` and it's more elegant :)

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("gallery=");
query.append(android.net.Uri.encode(value));
```

Comment: Correct usage is android.net.Uri.encode(value,":/"), Where second argument is list of characters which shouldn't be encoded

Comment: @Softec I removed the optional second argument per your comment.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to replace all spaces, not only white.

the simplest way is to use

```
"url_with_spaces".replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

However, you should consider also other characters in the URL. See [What is the recommended way to escape HTML symbols in plain Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

Comment: what if you want to encode the blue, or the red spaces in the url?

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "my string";
s=s.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that needs space characters to be encoded as a `%20` value instead of a `+` value, use:

```
String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(originalString,"UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`URIUtil.encodePath`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil.html#encodePath%28java.lang.String%29) method from the api `org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil`.

This should do the trick for you.