# Page encoding in JSP

Tags: ajax, jsp, encoding

I am having two jsp say "**first.jsp"** and "**second.jsp"** which is included in "**first.jsp**". I wanted to display trade mark symbol in jsp so I used

```
  <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

in "**first.jsp**" which is working fine when first time page is loading. But when I am invoking ajax request then result is coming in "**second.jsp**"  which is included in "**first.jsp**" and this time trade mark symbol is **not** displaying properly. It displays some block instead of trade mark symbol.

When I saw viewSource there I got symbol displaying properly.

I also tried using **content-type** but still no luck.

**EDITED**

After changing editors encoding setting to UTF-8 it is working on localhost but fails on test server.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the question I mentioned that In one JSP (**first.jsp**) I am including another jsp say **second.jsp** in the javascript using "**innerHtml()**" and that is the point where problem was there.

I replaced that part with JQueries "**html()**" function. And it WORK for me. The reason behind is that as innerHtml() doesnt execute the scripting code where as JQueries html() function executing scripting code.

So replacing **innerHtml()** function with Jqueries **html()** function to add another jsp did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `&trade;` entitity, then it should be displayed regardless of encoding.

(but I agree it would be better to get the encoding working correctly)

Comment: In java code I tried to replace trade mark character with &trade; but it wont work on server it is working on localhost

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have "UTF-8" encoding to show copyright character. Simplest solution to your problem is to insert ascii code of copyright symbol using HTML escape sequence. For your case, that would be `&#169;`.

You can easily find a list of all character codes on web ([here](http://www.hypergurl.com/asciisymbols.html), for example).

Also you can find code that does HTML escaping for you. Just pass a string and get back a string with all characters escaped correctly.

See this question: [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

---

**EDIT**

See this link for a [running sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tahir/jTwgy/1/)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am not able to find way to insert ascii code of trademark symbol. From which character exactly I have to replace because I am just getting square bolck instead of trademark character.

Comment: See the updated answer for a link to sample code. This is not jsp but this shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Thanks Tahir, but my question is I am getting unknown character from server side then how I replaced that character with "&#153;" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

on **every** JSP. Not only the master JSPs, but also the include JSPs and JSPs which are abused as ajax response servlets.

Comment: Then the files are not saved as UTF-8. Check your editor settings.

Comment: Already tried....I am using RAD & I changed editors encoding settings to UTF-8 after that it is working on localhost but its not working on test server.

Comment: Already tried? Why didn't you mention that in the question then? It is a pretty important symptom that it works local but not on testserver.