# Non-unicode chars in UTF-8 encoded JSP page in Android Webview

Tags: android, mongodb, jsp, unicode, utf-8

I have a JSP page, with some info pulled from Mongo DB. The outcome HTML page has UTF-8 encoding. Occasionally this char is being pulled from the DB: `–`, the en dash. When the page displayed in browser - this char is being displayed OK. But when in Android Webview - I see a question mark instead of it.

Any ideas how to solve it without touching the Mongo DB?

**EDIT**

Short HTML outcome:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ....
</head>
...
<div class="photo_description">
    <h1>
        <span class="text-ellipsis">
            NY – The sunrise
        </span>
    </h1>
    <div class="button">
        <div class="btn-txt">
            View
        </div>
    </div>
        ...
</div>
...
```

Notice the dash in the `<span>` element.

Comment: Can you post a shortened version of your HTML outcome here?

Comment: @Artjom Edited my post.

Comment: Did you already checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933069/android-webview-with-garbled-utf-8-characters)?

Comment: @Artjom Yep, already did. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134411/jstl-escaping-special-characters):

```
${fn:escapeXml(photoTitle)}
```