# Tagsoup , tag as text to another tag

Tags: java, tag-soup

hello guys i hope this message finds you all well.
So my questions has to do with tagsoup , what i want to achieve is to have a tag as a text of another tag, in specific , i want the `<a href="http://twitter.com/devices" rel="nofollow">`to be the TEXT of the tag `<SOURCE>` , but i cannot seem to do it since each time it sees an open pointy bracket it interprets that as a new tag. So is there any way to perform this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of `>` and `<`? Or just using some library to html-escape the the text?

Edit: see for example [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

Comment: unfortunately i need the text to remain exactly as it is. Is there any alternative to that ?

Comment: I don't think so. Also why do you need the text to be exactly as it is?