# Displaying html characters through java bean

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have a java bean which get populated from DB. The fields of bean may contain characters like **<** or . Right now when i am trying to display them, the string get truncated from the point where any of these character appear.

So if i have 
`this is a </ test message and i want to see if it displays`. HTML will display only `this is a` string only. How can i display full string.

P.S:
For some reasons, I can't change string in the database. I have to rely whatever i have in db.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1265282/738746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple solution, see methods of the `String` class:

- String.replace()
- String.replaceAll()
- String.replaceFirst()

**Note:** replaceAll and replaceFirst require a regex pattern to match, not a plain match string. Check `Pattern` class on how to build a suitable regex.

Remember that in HTML, the symbols < and > can be displayed using `&lt;` and `&gt;`. If you don't understand what I'm talking about, just View Source on this page and find my last sentence in the source.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to surround the text with the HTML tag "pre"

The other option is to escape the text to make it XML friendly.  Commons-lang has a utility for this.  http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html