# DOM parser can not parse special character

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am using Dom parser for xml parsing and it works fine in android 4. But it can not parse '&' in android 2.  For example..if string "Android & iPhone" then it takes only "Android". Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the ampersand is a special character in XML. Try using `&amp;` instead.

EDIT:

To escape all the specail characters, you could use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(String str)` from the [Apache commons library](http://commons.apache.org/), as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java).

You can download the Apache commons library [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi).

Comment: I know but the string comes from api.. How can I replace ?

Comment: which file I have to download ?

Comment: when I use...                                                     import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml;                 it gives me error.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? Please accept the answer if so.

Answer (score 0):

You can also treat it as XPL and process it directly to XML. XPL (eXtensible Process Language) is just like XML, but it allows the XML "special characters" in text elements. [link to eXtensible Process Language](http://hll.nu)