# How to send a sentence having space as an argument in Httpget in android

Tags: android

I have an `Httpget` request which send address of a person to the server. Once it reach at server i will receive a confirmation message as `Success`. I have given a toast message to print the received string. I am getting the toast message while I am typing a line without space.
But the problem is that, when I am giving a sentence including space it is getting error
forcefully closing the emulator.

The error showed in the `logcat` is as follows:

```
 06-21 15:01:10.083: E/AndroidRuntime(513): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 53: http://r4m.co/android/api.php?type=10&maintainance=Mohammed Shehnad.b
```

Can anybody give a suggestion for my problem..

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can escape your request parameter using :

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

URLEncoder.encode(string, charsetName);
```