# Replace newline with <br/> and spaces with &emsp; inside <code> tags

Tags: java, regex

I would like to replace newlines and spaces with their counterparts so they get styled correctly in my android app.

I would like to know the best approach for this regex. I've tried to do this to replace newlines with `<br />`:

```
string.replaceAll("@<code>.*\\n*</code>@si", "<br />");
```

But it didn't work. For the double space replacing, I haven't been able to come up with anything.

So This is what I want to achieve:

From `\n` to `<br />`, and from "double unencoded space" to `&emsp;`.

Comment: Can't you just use the `PRE` tag? That's what it's for, *sort of*.

Comment: You can try the Apache Commons Lang library as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java

Comment: @amn This is for an Android Textview, and that does not support `pre` tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Java you can do that in 2 replace calls:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\r?\\n", "<br />");
string = string.replace("  ", " &emsp;");
```

#### EDIT:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?i)(?<=<code>)(.+?)(?=</code>)").matcher(string);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String grp = m.group(1).replaceAll("\\r?\\n", "<br />");
    grp = grp.replace("  ", " &emsp;");
    m.appendReplacement(buf, grp);
}
m.appendTail(buf);
// buf.toString() is your replaced string
```

I purposefully used `String#replace` in 2nd call because we're not really using any regex there.

Also as @amn commented you can wrap your string in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags and avoid these replacements.

Comment: I need the regex to only act on <code> tags, and not the entire String.

Comment: ok try it now. It will help if you can provide sample value of input string.

Comment: This works, but there is one problem. I lose the `<code>` tags in the String. What could cause that?

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted to strip out code tag. That's why I didn't capture it. Let me make an edit.