# How to delete HTML and it's content in Java?

Tags: java, html, regex

I've got string `<strong>Foo</strong>`. I want to delete HTML tags from this string even with it's content. In this example expression must return `""` (empty string). How should I do this?

Comment: You mean `null`, or you mean an empty string `""` ??

Comment: May be duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java

Comment: Can your data contain same nested tags like `<b>x<b>y</b>z</b>`? If yes then it will be probably impossible with regex in Java since it doesn't support recursion yet.

Comment: You could do it with a state machine

Comment: No. My string looks like `bar<strong>foo</strong>`. All I want is `bar`

Comment: He's asking if some data could have something like

"bar<html><head></head><body><p>foo</p></body></html>" in it. If there cannot be nested html in your data then you could do it trivially with a regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the html you're trying to remove wouldn't have any nested html tags; here's a simple regex based solution. You can assign tag name to `tag` for convenience and the regex would adjust accordingly.

```
String tag = "strong";
String str = "This is <strong>Foo</strong>Bar.";

String regex = "<\\s*" + tag + "[^>]*>[^<]*</\\s*" + tag + "\\s*>";

System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regex, "")); // This is Bar.
```

The regex accommodates for any extra tag attributes like `<strong class="bold">` etc. <s>but could break if</s> and is updated to take care of slightly ill-formatted html like unnecessary white spaces or new lines here and there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are claiming that you don't have nested tags you can try using `"<([^>]+)>.*?</\\1>`

```
String data = "bar<strong>foo</strong>yyy<strong>zzz</strong>";
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("<([^>]+)>.*?</\\1>", ""));
```

ouptut

```
baryyy
```

Comment: @downvoter care to explain your action?