# Don't read '&lt;' with XML-file in JLabel

Tags: java, html, xml, swing, jlabel

I have a XML-file that contains the symbol '**&lt (<)**':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<parent>
    <child>&lt;100</child>
</parent>
```

I read this value using the method:

```
public String getValue(String parentTag, int parentIndex)
{
   Node root = m_doc.getElementsByTagName(parentTag).item(parentIndex); 
   return root.getTextContent();
}
```

And displays it in a **JLabel** with **HTML**:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><b>"+docXml.getValue("negative", 0) +"</b></html>");
```

But this value is shown *without* the symbol **<**. If you do not use HTML, it is displayed. How to make that this symbol is **shown with HTML**? Thanks!

P.S. Symbol **&gt (>)** displayed correctly !

Comment: You probably need to escape the content you try to display. You could use apache commons for that `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String)` should do the trick. Else you can manually escape the 5 more common characters to escape: `&`-->`&amp`;, <-->`&lt;`, `>`-->`&gt`, `'` --> `&#x27;`, `"` --> `&#x22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node.getTextContent()` already returns unescaped text. So when you try to get text from your `<child>`, what you get back is `<100`.

JLabel assumes that < is part of an invalid opening tag for an html element, and drops it.

You can see correct text when using`&gt`, because `>` is acceptable for `JLabel`.

To fix the problem, before adding text to `JLabel`, you can escape back what you got from your XML document.

e.g. using [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String)) (note that this will escape only `&lt;`
`&gt;` 
`&amp;`
`&apos;` 
`&quot;` characters. Otherwise take a look at [escapeHtml](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String)))

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><b>"+StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(docXml.getValue("negative", 0)) +"</b></html>");
```

Unfortunately this information lacks in [Node.getTextContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()) docs, so you have to be carefull always, and do not rely on the returned text, if your XML contains escaped text.

Comment: Although in this case escapeHtml and escapeXml will return the same thing, it feels a bit strange to use escapeXml in an HTML context, no?

Comment: I think that clearly depends on needs. I personally choose escapeXml, whenever I need only basic 5 escapes, If I am not sure - I go with escapeHtml. Also in lang3 , there is escapeHtml4, and escapeHtml3 , so instead of bothering myself which one to use, I just go with escapeXml.

Comment: Oh, Thank you for your detailed reply !  I need to use the following ? `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;`.

Comment: @Tomas Yes you need ```org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils```. You do not need FileUtils (for escaping at least)

Comment: @Guillaume Polet Thanks anyway for mentioning it, I have added my answer to prevent confusion.

Comment: This is an external library ?

Comment: @Tomas Yes, this is from apache commons - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/ . As an alternative, if you are using Spring by a chance, you can try this one http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html  Or see this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java you can find some alternatives how to escape html in Java. Hope that helps