# Javascript new line and double quote escape using java

Tags: java, javascript, regex, escaping

I have to call some Javascript functions from my Java code and some strings as parameter. The string may contain **new line** and **double/single quote**. So I want to escape the **new line** and **double quote** using java so that it can be passed smoothly to JS method? How to do the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you have tried so far?

Comment: We could really use some examples here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Apache common lib. `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(String)` using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `st.replaceAll("\\s+","")` - removes all whitespaces and non visible characters such as tab, `\n` and for removing single quotes use `str.replace("'", "")` and so on for similar things.

Comment: I do want to replace the those characters, I need them in javascript, so I want to just escape them.