# Removing html tags

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a professor requesting that we remove HTML tags (anything in < and >) without the use of the removeAll method.

I currently have this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("src/HTML_1.txt"));
    while (input.hasNext())
    {
        String html = input.next();
        System.out.println(stripHtmlTags(html));
    }

}

static String stripHtmlTags(String html)
{
    int i;
    String[] str = html.split("");
    String s = "";
    boolean tag = false;

    for (i = html.indexOf("<"); i < html.indexOf(">"); i++) 
    {
        tag = true;
    }

    if (!tag) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
        {
            s += str[i];
        }
    }
    return s;   
}
```

This is what is inside the file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My web page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>There are many pictures of my cat here,
as well as my <b>very cool</b> blog page,
which contains <font color="red">awesome
stuff about my trip to Vegas.</p>


Here's my cat now:<img src="cat.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

This is what the output should look like:

```
My web page


There are many pictures of my cat here,
as well as my very cool blog page,
which contains awesome
stuff about my trip to Vegas.


Here's my cat now:
```

Comment: To start with, you never assign the result of the method `stripHtmlTags` to anything, nor do you display anything

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki - it looks like they're supposed to remove the HTML tags, not escape them?

Comment: @yarivt:  I'm sorry but that doesn't help very much.

Comment: If they have an entire html page in txt file, then they would strip it to zero (if it is to remove, not escape the tags), because all page is in <html> tag

Comment: @Makoto neither is getting someone to do your homework for you. i think the basic thing is to learn to debug your code, or go online and search how to do for-loop

Comment: @yarivt: Give them the benefit of the doubt?  Perhaps they're at their wit's end and are trying to figure out a solution.  There's no harm in them asking a question in that vein, seriously.  Telling them to "just go debug the code" is about as constructive as pointing out that they have a problem.

Comment: The simply solution would be to use a regular expression and `String#split`.  You could also use `String#indexOf` to find where the first `>` and next `<` characters are and match everything else in between...

Comment: @Makoto while i dont 100% agree with you, i do respect your opinion. why aren't you just giving OP the answer then

Comment: You need to loop through the text until you reach the end.  You could simply inspect the current character at the current index and check to see if it's a `<` and if it is, set a flag that until you reach a `>` character, you basically do nothing.  Otherwise, you should append the character to a `String` and do this till you reach the end of the `String`

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `String#indexOf` and `String#substring` and basically "cut" the text that isn't within `<...>` to another `String`, doing this until you've run out of text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `String` is immutable in Java + You never display anything

I recommend you `close` your `Scanner` when done with it (as a best practice), and reading the `HTML_1.txt` file from the user's HOME directory. The simplest way to `close` is a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), "HTML_1.txt"))) {
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String html = stripHtmlTags(input.nextLine().trim());
            if (!html.isEmpty()) { // <-- removes empty lines.
                System.out.println(html);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Because `String` is immutable I would recommend a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to remove the HTML tags like

```
static String stripHtmlTags(String html) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(html);
    int open;
    while ((open = sb.indexOf("<")) != -1) {
        int close = sb.indexOf(">", open + 1);
        sb.delete(open, close + 1);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

When I run the above I get

```
My web page
There are many pictures of my cat here,
as well as my very cool blog page,
which contains awesome
stuff about my trip to Vegas.
Here's my cat now:
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually haven't learned StringBuilder yet but I'm looking it up.  It does seem a lot more practical.

The reason why I didn't close my scanner is because our professor actually advised against closing the scanner.  He mentioned something about how it would cause problems later on.

Comment: @JessicaFura You shouldn't `close` a `Scanner` that's wrapping `System.in`. You **should** `close` a `Scanner` that's backed by a `File`, or you leak a file handle. That doesn't matter in a program that terminates immediately, but it might cause a production issue in a long running process.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm going insane you aren't printing anything. The changes are returned and immediately are destroyed since no function or variable is receiving the returned string.

Change

```
stripHtmlTags(html);
```

to

```
System.out.println(stripHtmlTags(html));
```

Also you're setting tag true or false the applying that to the entire line. You need to keep track if you're in a tag and ignore those characters if you are.

So loop through each letter of string html  . If it is a < you know that a tag is starting, else if it is a > a tag is ending, if it isn't either of these (anything else) then check if you're in a tag (boolean tag) if you aren't add it to the string.

Comment: You're going insane.  Nothing's printing, but nothing's coming back from the method *either*.

Comment: @Shahzeb:  It's literally *a* point.  You get ten of 'em if you answer correctly.

Comment: It was a comment, I decided to look more but thanks for the love. For whatever reason this is setup so that it takes more rep to make a comment then offer a solution. But really you need to calm yourselves. It's a person learning and you should be nudging them in the right direction. So what's wrong or bad with pointing out an issue? The other issues don't make that one any less true.

Comment: The problem here is that the issue you're pointing out isn't *the* issue.  It's certainly the case that nothing's being printed, but *that's not the bug.*

Comment: You're right it isn't the issue because there's more than one issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out! I was actually under the assumption that return would automatically print out what ever was in the variable. I think I may be rushing through this course a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Like most things in life, there is more then one way to get this to work, but to the main problem...

```
for (i = html.indexOf("<"); i < html.indexOf(">"); i++) {
    tag = true;
}

if (!tag) {
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        s += str[i];
    }
}
```

The text starts with `<html>`, this means that when the first `for-loop` ends, `i` will equal `4` and `tag` will be `true`, which means it skips the `if` block and then...exists the method...

You need to keep looping until you run out of text...

The simplest solution might be to simply start at the start of the `String` and check each character, ignoring everything between `<...>`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
boolean ignore = false;
for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
    if (text.charAt(index) == '<') {
        ignore = true;
    } else if (text.charAt(index) == '>') {
        ignore = false;
    } else if (!ignore) {
        sb.append(text.charAt(index));
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Then make sure you print the result `System.out.println(stripHtmlTags(html));`

Another solution (which would be more efficient), would be to trim off all the `<...>` content from the start of the `String`, until there is nothing left of the `String`...

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(text);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(64);
int index = 0;
while (html.length() > 0) {

    int startIndex = html.indexOf(">");
    if (index == -1) {
        // Only plain text remaining...
        result.append(html.toString());
        html.delete(0, html.length());
    } else {
        html.delete(0, startIndex + 1);
        int endIndex = html.indexOf("<");
        if (endIndex > 0) {
            result.append(html.substring(0, endIndex));
            html.delete(0, endIndex);
        }
    }

}
return result.toString();
```

I've used `StringBuilder` here as it's more efficient then trying to do `String` concatenation or assigning the results of `String#substring` back to another `String`

And if you want to be "super", you could use regular expression and `String#split`

```
String[] parts = text.split("<(.*?)>");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
for (String part : parts) {
    sb.append(part);
}
return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

A small recursive method

```
static String stripHtmlTags2(String html)
{           
    int startIndex = html.indexOf("<");
    int endIndex = html.indexOf(">");
    String stripedString = html;
    //Assuming an end for every start tag
    if (startIndex!=-1){
        stripedString = html.substring(0,startIndex);           
        stripedString = stripedString+html.substring(endIndex+1);
        stripedString = stripHtmlTags2(stripedString);
    }

    return stripedString;
}
```

Use like (in your main)

```
StringBuilder htmlFreeString = new StringBuilder();
while (input.hasNextLine())
  {
       String html = input.nextLine();
       htmlFreeString.append(stripHtmlTags2(html));
   }
 System.out.print(htmlFreeString.toString());
```