# Script security search box of application

Tags: javascript, java, security

I am doing a web project using Java MVC, it has one search box. I am getting the search string from this text box and in turn calling a Javascript search script method. It in turn calls a Web service to search. Now if I search for a script like:

```
<script>alert("helllooooo")<\script >
```

then it alerts helloooo as well as searches using services. How can I avoid evaluating a script in this situation.

Comment: "Avoid working of script"?? What do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, do something usual for such security measures

Comment: @αƞjiβ, I guess what you want to do is prevent a user from executing a javascript entered into the search box?

Comment: Yeah along with CSS or HTML

Answer (score 0):

You would have to sanitize the input before sending it to your web service or searching on it.

By sanitizing it would mean escaping all HTML and Javascript tags from the input string.

Check the [Apache StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) class for such methods like `escapeJava`, `escapeJavascript` etc. You would have to do this on the web service end.
If you want this to happen on the javascript side itself you would have to write a Javascript function that would explicitly escape the HTML and JS special characters (notably the  tags)

Comment: Mainly If I enter one script it should not work, example if I search alert(hello ) this should not executed in the client side as well as search string without script should be passed to the service

Comment: No. This is a security issue. You can't rely on client-side validation because it can be bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability here. You need to do server-side escaping to prevent exploitation. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top) has several potential solutions. You can also refer to the [OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Client-side escaping is insufficient because an attacker will bypass your client-side code when performing an attack.

Comment: if I give one alert script, am getting alert. Actually when it's working, after getting Web services result or before or when I click the search button it's self?

Comment: You want to do the escaping just before returning the data to the client

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the < and > like this :

```
var html = document.getElementById("searchboxid").value;
html = html.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

Comment: This is insufficient. You should escape more chars like `"`.