# How to encode href url in a scriptlet?

Tags: java, html

In my code I have a scriptlet that sets the href equal to a value that may contain spaces.

Here is an example:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<%=supportGroup%>">Support group: <%=supportGroup%></a>
```

The value of supportGroup is something like ENT-ESD VALUE. This value is an id to a div as well. I am wondering of a way to encode this value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Either of these may help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java

Comment: what template engine do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JSP you can use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html).

```
<c:url value="https://www.google.com/" var="url" />

<a href="${url}">Link</a>
```

Result:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Link</a>
```

or

```
<c:url value="https://www.google.com/" var="url">
     <c:param name="q" value="anything" />
</c:url>

<a href="${url}">Link</a>
```

Result:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/?q=anything">Link</a>
```