# Exclude five basic XML entities when using StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()

Tags: java, html, stringescapeutils

I am trying to `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String string)` to convert the special characters on my web page to HTML entities. But it also escapes the five basic XML entities which are **<, >, ", ', and &**, which makes my HTML not render correctly since the mentioned characters were escaped.

So what I do after that is use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(String string)` to return **<, >, ", ', and &** back to their single character form.

Is there any other way to do this? Like not include the 5 entities I mentioned when StringEscapeUtils does HTML escaping?

Comment: Why do it at all? Why not use a character encoding that allows all those characters to be displayed as-is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java

Comment: The html that I'm trying to escape will be sent as an email. So if the one receiving it has different character encoding, it displays as "?". That's why I'm trying to put in html entity form all characters.

Comment: An e-mail message should also include the character set. Unless the one receiving it has an email client from the '90s or so, then the content-type of the message part should do the trick. And of course, you should add the appropriate `meta` tag to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own translator:

```
public static final CharSequenceTranslator ESCAPE_HTML4 = new AggregateTranslator(
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_ESCAPE),
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_ESCAPE)
            );
```

This particualr translator leaves out the `EntityArrays.BASIC_ESCAPE()` data.

Thus, it will convert special characters and ommit the HTML tags.

Convert your `text` variable using:

```
text = ESCAPE_HTML4.translate(text);
```