# How do you generate an HTML page by passing it Java variables?

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx

Explanation.
I am trying to figure out how to pass data in a way that will generate an HTML page based on user input from a JavaFX application.

My company needs a quick way to generate 5 email signatures for each employee, one for each of our child companies, all from the same input data. i.e.

```
[Company One Image]
*fName* *lName* | *Title*
*Phone* | *Fax*
*fName*.lName@company1.com

[Company Two Image]
*fName* *lName* | *Title*
*Phone* | *Fax*
*fName*.lName@company2.com
```

...etc

Basically I am converting JavaFX TextField to String and then trying to inject that into an HTML.

Can I drop my HTML code straight into Strings, concatenating the input data in, then generate and open a .html?

```
String companyOneSig = "<img src= "yaddayadda"><br>" + fName + " " + lName;
```

Of course using proper escape characters...

Do I have to utilize JavaScript in some way to handle the variables?
Can I just write to a .txt?

If anyone can give me a direction without my laziness having to dig through API's.

Comment: The fastest way is definitely with string concat and [html escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1265282/4464702). If you need more than that, there are libraries called "template engines" which do exactly that (Thymeleaf, FreeMarker, etc...)

Comment: Yes, you can generate html using nothing but Java. You probably want to write it to an .html file though.

Comment: Awesome, I figured this much but I didn't want to get too far into it and find I just wasted limited time. I appreciate the quick responses @RAnders00

Comment: and @CheifTwoPencils