# What's the difference between Android's Html.escapeHtml and TextUtils.htmlEncode ? When should I use one or the other?

Tags: android, android-webview, html-entities, html-encode, html-escape

Android has two different ways to escape / encode HTML characters /  entities in Strings:

- [`Html.escapeHtml(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.CharSequence)), added in API 16 (Android 4.1). The docs say:

  > Returns an HTML escaped representation of the given plain text.
- [`TextUtils.htmlEncode(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#htmlEncode(java.lang.String)) For this one, the docs say:

  > Html-encode the string.

Reading the docs, they both seem to do pretty much the same thing, but, when testing them, I get some pretty mysterious (to me) output.

Eg. With the input: `<p>This is a quote ". This is a euro symbol: €. <b>This is some bold text</b></p>`

- `Html.escapeHtml` gives:

  ```
  &lt;p&gt;This is a quote ". This is a euro symbol: &#8364;. &lt;b&gt;This is some bold text&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
  ```
- Whereas `TextUtils.htmlEncode` gives:

  ```
  &lt;p&gt;This is a quote &quot;. This is a euro symbol: €. &lt;b&gt;This is some bold text&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
  ```

So it seems that the second escapes / encodes the quote (**"**), but the first doesn't, although the first encodes the Euro symbol, but the second doesn't. I'm confused.

---

So what's the difference between these two methods ? Which characters does each escape / encode ? What's the difference between *encoding* and *escaping* here ? When should I use one or the other (or should I, gasp, use them both together ?) ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can compare their sources:

This is what `Html.escapeHtml` uses underneath:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d59921149bb5948ffbcb9a9e832e9ac1538e05a0/core/java/android/text/Html.java#L387

This is `TextUtils.htmlEncode`:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d59921149bb5948ffbcb9a9e832e9ac1538e05a0/core/java/android/text/TextUtils.java#L1361

As you can see, the latter only quotes certain characters that are reserved for markup in HTML, while the former also encodes non-ASCII characters, so they can be represented in ASCII.

Thus, if your input only contains Latin characters (which is usually unlikely nowadays), or you have set up Unicode in your HTML page properly, and can go along with `TextUtils.htmlEncode`. Whereas if you need to ensure that your text works even if transmitted via 7-bit channels, use `Html.escapeHtml`.

As for the different treating of the quote character (`"`) -- it only needs to be escaped inside attribute values (see [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2)), so if you are not putting your text there, you should be fine.

Thus, my personal choice would be `Html.escapeHtml`, as it seems to be more versatile.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the explanation of things of when to use what and why, which is what I was unsure about. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the references and the explanation