# Escaping a URL in Java

Tags: java, web, encoding

I have the following URL I want to escape :

```
http://BUCKET_ENDPOINT/PATH_1/PATH_2/PATH_3/PATH_4/PATH_5/TEST NAME COULD BE WITH & AND OTHER SPECIAL CHARS.zip
```

I haven't found so far how to encode this string to match both storing in an HTML and encoded as a URL, e.g. '&' should be replaced with #26, space should be replaced with #20, etc

Java's URLEncoder will, for example, replace the spaces with a '+' sign, which isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: HTMLEscape and URLEncode are two different operations and for different purposes. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The main thing I want to achieve is to be able to download these files (built with the pattern I mentioned in the original post) when clicked on from an HTML page

Comment: Within a <a> tag, put the HTMLEscaped URL and in the HREF attribute put the URLEncoded URL. You can't get a single encoded value for both.

Comment: When I run URLEncoder.encode I'm still left with the '+' sign which results in failure to download the file, is there something I'm missing here ?

Comment: The order should be something like: 1. Use URLEncode and encode the URL
2. Construct your HTML
3. EscapeHTML content

Comment: try com.google.common.net.UrlEscapers from guava library. You must separately encode url path segment and url parameters (they have different characters to be escaped).

Comment: @Michal the URL path if I understand it correctly is http://BUCKET_ENDPOINT/PATH_1/PATH_2/PATH_3/PATH_4/PATH_5

while the path segment is TEST NAME COULD BE WITH & AND OTHER SPECIAL CHARS.zip

Do I understand it correctly ?

Comment: Url path segment is anything after BUCKET_ENDPOINT/. you should encode separately PATH_1,PATH_2, ..., TEST NAME ... . Here is nice explanation https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I haven't found so far how to encode this string to match both storing in an HTML and encoded as a URL

That's because there isn't any, since those are two separate things.

**Printing in HTML** should generally be done by replacing only `'`, `"`, `<`, `>` and `&` with `&apos;`, `&quot;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`. Here are examples doing that: [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java), the most trivial and easiest to reason with being

```
public static String encodeToHTML(String str) {
    return str
        .replace("'",  "&apos;")
        .replace("\"", "&quot;")
        .replace("<",  "&lt;")
        .replace(">",  "&gt;")
        .replace("&",  "&amp;");
}
```

Note that you need to have matching character set in your page, and be aware that if you for example print the url in an attribute field, requirements are a bit different.

**Encoding as an url** allows for a lot shorter list of characters. From [URLEncoder documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

> The alphanumeric characters "a" through "z", "A" through "Z" and "0"
>   through "9" remain the same.
>
> The special characters ".", "-", "*", and "_" remain the same.
>
> The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".
>
> All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into
>   one or more bytes using some encoding scheme. Then each byte is
>   represented by the 3-character string "%xy", where xy is the two-digit
>   hexadecimal representation of the byte.
>
> The recommended encoding scheme to use is UTF-8.

You'd get those with

```
String encoded = new java.net.URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

The above will give you HTML form encoding, which is close to what url encoding does, with a few noteable differences, the most relevant being `+` vs `%20`.  For that, you can do this on its output:

```
String encoded = encoded.replace("+", "%20");
```

Note also that you don't want to use url encoding for the whole `http://BUCKET_ENDPOINT/PATH_1/PATH_2/PATH_3/PATH_4/PATH_5/TEST NAME COULD BE WITH & AND OTHER SPECIAL CHARS.zip`, but to the last part of it, `TEST NAME COULD BE WITH & AND OTHER SPECIAL CHARS.zip`, and the individual path segments if they are not fixed.

If you are in a position that you need to generate the url *and* print it in html, first encode it as an url, then do html escaping.

Comment: NOTE that "java.net.URLEncoder.encode" is requiring Android API (LEVEL) 33+

Answer (score 0):

Since I already know that the path part of the URL doesn't need special escaping I decided to go with the solution proposed [here](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/encode-url-string/) to encode only the zip file name part which answers the need in this case

```
 String urlEscaped = URLEncoder.encode(URL_TO_ESCAPE, "UTF-8")
            .replaceAll("\+", "%20")
            .replaceAll("\%21", "!")
            .replaceAll("\%27", "'")
            .replaceAll("\%28", "(")
            .replaceAll("\%29", ")")
            .replaceAll("\%7E", "~");
```

Comment: "Since I already know that the path part of the URL doesn't need special escaping" .. well, why didn't you mention it in the question then? :) Also, there's really no need to use regular expressions here. you can just use replace() instead of replaceAll() and get rid of regular expression escapes.