# java escape string – for use in url

Tags: java, escaping

I want to use a string within a url:

```
some/url/<mystring>
```

My problem: `mystring` comes directly from a user input where it is allowed to type any special character including dangerous ones, like slash for example. I want to escape those.

EDIT: no, I do not want to escape HTML code. I want to escape the parts of a string, that could make the url directing elsewhere than to `url/to/{input}`. (for example `/` or `?`)

Comment: URL-escape then! Be careful, if and when you receive those later on in any of your flows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape your url with 

`String escapedURL=java.net.URLEncoder(url);`

Read more about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score -1):

1.Fetch the String from user input

2.So safety-checking

3.if ok send it to html if not display a warning or not found error maybe