# OWASP java-html-sanitizer - policy for unclosed tags

Tags: java, owasp

I am using the same example of `EbayPolicyExample.java` from the OWASP java-html-sanitizer, however, I have been facing some issues when the user writes something like:
`let's consider that x <n then we have ...`
So what happens is that every text after `<n` is removed.

How could I fix this issue and remains the string `<n`?

I tried to change the Policy a little bit, but I wasn't successful and it is possible to guess what letter the user will enter after `<`.

Note: the tag n is just an example, it should also work for any letter (e.g. `<o, <i, <y`)?

- **input**: `let's consider that x <n then we have ...`
- **actual output**: `let's consider that x`
- **expect output**: `let's consider that x <n then we have ...`

The link for the code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/master/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/examples/EbayPolicyExample.java

Comment: If you let your users submit HTML, then it should be valid HTML. So in this case the `<` should've been encoded as `&lt;` and there would be no problem. So it should be the responsibility of either the user or the tool you use that generates the HTML to make sure that it is valid.

Comment: @Ivar So I should allow all HTML tags and replace the `<` to encoded `&lt;` and on my front-end, I should treat it. It sounds good and valid.

Comment: It depends a bit on what you are trying to achieve. If you are replacing all `<` then no tags will be allowed to use. In which case there is no reason to use an HTML sanitizer. If you just want to be save from XSS then you should simply HTML Encode the input. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java) on how you can do that properly.

Comment: Thank you @Ivar, that is an interesting resolution. This helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to provide valid HTML in your input.
`<`  is a special character in HTML. It denotes the start of a tag.

You have to replace `<` with the corresponding HTML entity: `&lt;` in your input.

I the input is entered by the user, you have to pre-process it and make sure it actually is valid HTML. This post might be useful: [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

Comment: So if I use the scapingHTML I can totally ignore html tags. That is useful.