# Get encoded html content only from url in java

Tags: java, html, encode, jsoup

Is there a library in JAVA where I can encode HTML, but only content?

I have like

```
<div>Tél</div>
```

and I only want

```
<div>T&eacute;l</div>
```

instead of

```
&lt;div&gt;T&eacute;l<&lt;/div&gt;
```

I need this library to encode an entire HTML.
I have tried library JSoup but it has bugs when handling some objects.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to convert characters into their HTML entities in the first place? If you're using UTF-8, that should never be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a good idea to parse HTML using regex, that's a recipe for disaster.

So first look at this Q&A for HTML parsing in java: [Java HTML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing)

Once you are able to parse HTML and get internal HTML text then you can encode HTML in one of the these ways: [Is there a JDK class to do HTML encoding (but not URL encoding)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655746/is-there-a-jdk-class-to-do-html-encoding-but-not-url-encoding)