# How to I encode a string in java to vaild xHTML

Tags: java, string, xhtml, encode, html-encode

I am creating a web service in Java and I want to clean up my strings so they are valid xHTML.  I'd also like to preserve line breaks.

So for example, if my user enters a string like this:

```
 This course is offered <3> times a year & is scheduled for: 
 October 2011
 November 2012 and
 December  2013
```

I want to clean up the string to look like this:

```
 This course is offered &lt;3&gt; times a year &amp is scheduled for: 
 October 2011
 November 2012 and
 December  2013
```

How can I achieve this in Java?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to encode text data for XML in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439298/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655746/is-there-a-jdk-class-to-do-html-encoding-but-not-url-encoding) , but it requires taking a dependency on an external library since the JDK doesn't support it directly. check it out. The top answer on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't match your question exactly, but it appears that the answer is what you're looking for [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java).

Summary: StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml() from apache commons