# Decoding html to normal characters java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have socket stream which prints text to screen. If I have a string which should be "sælger", I receive  "s&AAOGlger".

My question: is there some kind of library that is able to decode the following piece of text so it becomes sælger?

The characters I'm using most is the danish letters æøåÆØÅ.

Best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a JDK class to do HTML encoding (but not URL encoding)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655746/is-there-a-jdk-class-to-do-html-encoding-but-not-url-encoding)

Comment: Don't you mean `"s&aelig;lger"` ?

Comment: Nope. My post is what i get. And it isnt a duplicate. The other post isen't even near a solution that works for me.
HTML special characters.